# Which process is sending outbound requests?

Tags: ubuntu, https, ufw

I recently installed a Ubuntu desktop (only additional programs being google-chrome and VLC). When I enabled UFW and blocked everything outgoing by default, I noticed a bunch of outgoing attempts without me doing anything.

- Many were to 1e100.com (to port 443, UDP). I am assuming chrome is
  sending these out
- Some were to deepintent.com (443, TCP), to infi.net (443, UDP) and some to IP addresses that don't have any rDNS entries

Is there a way for me to find out which processes are creating this chit chat?

Comment: There is no direct way to correlate network packages to processes. But maybe you find `nethogs` useful, which can display traffic grouped by processes https://github.com/raboof/nethogs

Comment: This link might help: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-auditd-monitor-network-connections-alex-maestretti

Answer (score 0):

Tools like `lsof`, `fuser`, `netstat`, or `ss` can help you identify the remote addresses of sockets one or many processes have opened, all of these support reverse address resolution, but it won't work if you blocked all outgoing traffic, read the manual pages for more information about these commands. You can try running `lsof` repeatedly for some time until relevant information is shown; for example, the following command runs `lsof` each 2 seconds until an IPv4 or IPv6 socket is opened, excluding listening TCP sockets.

`# until lsof -i4 -i6 -sTCP:^LISTEN; do sleep 2; done`